# Guardar salida comando en variable, consola de Windows

Tags: cmd, batch, msdos

Como el titulo dice intento meter el resultado de un comando en una variable y no encuentro información de como se puede hacer esto en Windows, todo lo que encuentro es en Linux.
Lo necesito en la bash de ms-DOS por compatibilidad.

Se lo básico de la programación en batch y he estado buscando esto pero no he tenido suerte. Mira quiero guardar el resultado de Date /T, que sería la fecha actual en una variable y luego cambiar la hora por esa fecha de una manera similar a estaDate $variable.Esa es mi idea

Comment: Escribe el comando que usas. De todas maneras deberías buscar información sobre programación batch que hay muchisisisisima info en la red.

Comment: Se lo básico de la programación en batch y he estado buscando esto pero no he tenido suerte. Mira quiero guardar el resultado de  `Date /T`, que sería la fecha actual en una variable  y luego cambiar la hora por esa fecha de una manera similar a esta`Date $variable`.Esa es mi idea

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade eso que has comentado para que lo vea más gente,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer no es tan sencillo como en Linux que es `A = $()`.

**Opción 1:**

Una forma es mandar toda la salida a un archivo, y luego volcar la salida del archivo a la variable:

```
application arg0 arg1 > temp.txt
set /p VAR=<temp.txt
```

**Opción 2:** 
Usando `for /f` que nos permite ejecutar el for sobre un comando. ([Ver Documentación](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html))

```
for /f %%i in ('application arg0 arg1') do set VAR=%%i
```

> Nota: el doble % en `%%I` escapa el % por que en un batch el % sirve para mostrar una variable.

Comment: he probado la segunda opción devolvía un `No se esperaba %%i en este momento`, probé quitarle un % de a cada i y me funcionó, no sé la razón, pero quería comentarla en caso de que a alguien más le pueda llegar a fallar, el comando quedaría de la siguiente manera:

`for /f %i in ('application arg0 arg1') do set VAR=%i`

Comment: un problema que no comenté es que la salida se corte en el primer espacio, al menos eso me pasó a mi con un comando que no es propio de Windows. El comando era `paste`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que suelo hacer es utilizar `for /f`. Por ejemplo:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('assoc .pptx') do set ext=%%a & set asoc=%%b
```

El comando anterior ejecuta el comando "assoc .pptx" el cual devuelve: `.pptx=PowerPoint.Show.12` y lo separo en dos variables %ext% y %asoc% haciendo referencia a la extensión y asociación de extensión de archivo.

La variable %ext% contiene ".pptx" y la variable %asoc% contiene "PowerPoint.Show.12"

Así se podría ver un ejemplo de guardar el resultado de un comando en varias variables.